# Is it possible to determine the UTC offset from two timestamps?

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, utc, datetimeoffset

Let's say I have two timestamps.  One is in UTC, and the other's timezone is unknown, but has a date and a time. The format of the latter is `YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS`.

Is it reasonable to get the offset from UTC by simply subtracting the second timestamp from the UTC one, then rounding the hours?

Is there a straightforward way to do this using Java? (e.g. Joda or JUT?)

Thanks!

A little background: These dates come from EXIF metadata of images. EXIF stores the `CreateDate` of an image in the format: `YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS` with no timezone information.  It also stores a UTC timestamp (sometimes) under `GPSTimeStamp`.  Using these two values, I was hoping to derive the offset in order to store the create date with it.  Although there is EXIF metadata for TZ offsets, cameras rarely record that.

Comment: don't forget about India - where the time zone is a half hour off from everywhere else.  (e.g. it's 3:19pm in Seattle right now, but 3:49am in India).

Comment: There are also timezones with [45 minutes of difference](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html). Anyway, you can't determine the timezone from the offset because usually more than one timezone can have the same offset: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets

Comment: You can determine the *offset*, but not the time zone. A time zone is not just the offset, but also the transitions to/from daylight savings, *and* the historical changes of the offset and transitions (time zones haven't always had the same rules).

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in my question.  I'm looking for the UTC offset.  I guess to get the Timezone as well, I'd need lon/lat (which I have available).

Comment: @EdwardQ.Bridges could you please [edit] the question then?

Comment: question updated!

Comment: A `java.sql.Timestamp` doesn't have a time zone, and value is always in UTC. Time zone is applied when *displaying* the value. Please edit question and clarify what you mean by "timestamp", e.g. by showing example values.

Comment: Indeed, the inputs and expected outputs would help, because it's still unclear to me. e.g., if you have 2017-08-24 at 10 AM UTC and a local time (at the same date) 11:35 AM, would you round the offset to 1 or 2 hours? (Not considering 30/45 minutes offsets) Where do those dates come from? Are you going to compare with the current date/time in UTC or a predefined value? And so on...

Comment: For the calculation I clearly recommend `java.time`, the modern Java date & time API. It has supplanted both the old classes (like `Timestamp`)  and Joda-Time. And yes, it sounds pretty straightforward if you could explain what input you are having more clearly.

Comment: Timestamps, by definition, don't have UTC offset: they're in UTC! If you said "two string representations", that would have more sense.

Comment: For the sake of completeness [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) does not define a timestamp as necessarily in UTC (though most of the examples are). I agree that the question is utterly unclear about what is meant by “timestamp”. And if two timestamps denote the same point in time, subtracting them ought to yield 0, no matter any time zone offsets. @OlivierGrégoire

Comment: Indeed a Unix Timestamp is in UTC.  However an ordinary timestamp (as @OleVV points out) is just a record of an instant of time -- given that I point out in my question the presence/absence of timezone offset, I'm not sure where your confusion is @OlivierGrégoire?

Comment: @EdwardQ.Bridges If it's an instant in time (and it is), it's not "an instant in time *at a specific location*". Meaning that it is not dependant on the timezone. So by usual computer definition (since you use it in computers, since you post it on SE), it's in UTC. That's about the timestamp. Now you're actually working with string representations which, you imply, are incomplete because they don't define the timezone, which is... allowed for a local string representation. So you should not use the word "timestamp". That's all I'm saying. I'm not confused: I'm pointing out inaccuracies.

Comment: The fact is, my question clearly states that I have two timestamps, one with a timezone and one without, which is merely the extent of the question.  As such it's not inaccurate.  You're pulling in context (pedantry regarding "timestamp" vs. a "Unix Timestamp") that is unnecessary for answering the question and just adds confusion.  I think if you were to step back and re-read the question you'd see that @OlivierGrégoire.

Comment: "The fact is, my question clearly states"... The fact is that 3 people already found that your question is unclear and voted to close because it is unclear.

Comment: I'm just not sure of a more concise way to describe an instant of time that does not include a timezone, which is what I have, other than "timestamp" (which usage is consistent with the dictionary definition).  A Unix Timestamp by definition, includes a timezone/offset (UTC). I did not refer to it that way.  Neither of the values I have are a Unix Timestamp, they are simply instants of time.  One of which includes a timezone.  I've clarified in my answer.  Unfortunately, there are 3 people out there who appear to be as confused as you.  Not sure what I can do about that.  Have a nice day.

Comment: Well, for one, you haven't put any code in the question. You mix terms. The two first comments show that you should get some litterature about how timezones work, and you don't act. More... Your answer show that you discarded these comments entirely, without even explaining how you would round. Also, this question could probably (but not surely) have been better received on [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). All in all, this is rather surprising from someone with ~4k rep. So yes, this is a bad question. It happens. No worries. You got your result, cool.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has gotten blown way out of proportion, where I was asking if there were any edge cases that I hadn't considered around getting the offset in hours between two timestamps.  RE: the first two comments, were referring to my original title mistakenly referring to timezones, which was updated.  My answer illustrates how I would round (getting the ceiling at hourly precision), so I'm surprised about your point there, but it seems like you want to drag this out.  If you want to push your points further, feel free to take to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
public static ZoneOffset determineTimeZoneOffset(OffsetDateTime localTime, OffsetDateTime utcTime) {
  if(utcTime == null || localTime == null) {
    return null;
  }

  OffsetDateTime ceilingUtc = utcTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS).plusHours(1);
  OffsetDateTime ceilingLocal = localTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS).plusHours(1);

  int offsetHours = (int)ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(ceilingUtc, ceilingLocal);

  return ZoneOffset.ofHours(offsetHours);
}
```

- Warnings about truncating to hours are well taken, but for the purposes of the application this is for we don't need to go that far with it.  However, it'd be easy enough I imagine to truncate using `ChronoUnit.MINUTES` or even seconds. An interesting exercise that Ole V.V. helpfully pointed out.
- Not sure why this was being downvoted -- maybe the confusion around the meaning of a timestamp.  I think it was pretty clear from the question that I was referring to a generic timestamp (as Ole V.V. and others noted).  I hope the downvoters reread the question and adjust their assessment.
- While I don't really consider it relevant to the question, these dates come from EXIF metadata of images.  EXIF stores the `CreateDate` of an image in the format: `YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS` with no timezone information.  It also stores a UTC timestamp (sometimes) under `GPSTimeStamp`.  Using these two values, I was hoping to derive the offset in order to store the create date with it.  Although there is EXIF metadata for TZ offsets, cameras rarely record that.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, it looks fine. Is there any point in adding 1 hour to each of the times before finding the number of hours between them (`plusHours(1)`)? You might just use the floor instead of the ceiling?

Comment: Hi -- thanks for updating the question -- hope it helps others.  Using the floor (by just truncating() without the additional call to plus()) would give an equivalent result -- the beginning of the hour rather than the top of the hour.  It's a flip of the coin, and depends on the application.  For my purposes, using the ceiling fit the application.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I probably have not understood the exact format or data type of your two “timestamps”. With this reservation here’s a suggestion.

```
    String dateTimeStringUtc = "2017-08-25T11:46:47.307";
    // for the sake of the example I took North Korean time; don’t tell anyone just yet :-)
    String dateTimeStringUnknownOffset = "2017-08-25T20:16:47.307";
    
    LocalDateTime utcTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStringUtc);
    LocalDateTime unknownOffsetTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeStringUnknownOffset);
    long offsetSeconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(utcTime, unknownOffsetTime);
    if (Math.abs(offsetSeconds) > 64800) { // out of range
        System.out.println("The time strings cannot represent the same time");
    } else {
        ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds((int) offsetSeconds);
        System.out.println("The zone offset is " + offset);
    }
```

This prints:

```
The zone offset is +08:30
```

As discussed in the comments, it’s generally a poor idea to round to whole hours. These days it may be safe to round to a quarter of an hour, but I’d hesitate, who knows whether some place will introduce an offset of 8:20 next year? Historically zone offsets with seconds have existed, so if your timestamps denote “the good old days”, you should probably avoid any rounding.